# Manipulate error with ViewPoint

Tags: graphics3d, manipulate

I have the following code that shows `n` spheres, but also allows you to reset the view if the graphic is rotated:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[
  Sphere[{0, 0, #}] & /@ Range[n],
  ViewPoint -> Dynamic@v[[1]],
  ViewVertical -> Dynamic@v[[2]],
  ViewAngle -> Dynamic@v[[3]],
  ViewCenter -> Dynamic@v[[4]]
  ],
 {{n, 3}, 2, 12, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{v, {{-2, 2, 2}, Automatic, Automatic, Automatic}}, 
  Button["Reset", v = {{-2, 2, 2}, Automatic, Automatic, Automatic}] &}
 ]
```

After executing, if I slide the `n` slider, I get an error message:

[image]

If I rotate the graphic, this error no longer occurs. Even after I hit the Reset button

Comment: If you copy the graphic and paste it, the FE crashes. Ouch. See also https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/63756534#63756534

Comment: I just got an email (sent a few hours ago) from WRI that the behavior I posted in chat is a bug. I think this is probably related.  [CASE:5049360]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A half solution:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[
  Sphere[{0, 0, #}] & /@ Range[n] // Dynamic,
  ViewPoint -> Dynamic@v[[1]],
  ViewVertical -> Dynamic@v[[2]],
  ViewAngle -> Dynamic@v[[3]],
  ViewCenter -> Dynamic@v[[4]]
  ],
 {{n, 3}, 2, 12, 1,
  Appearance -> "Labeled",
  TrackingFunction -> ((v = N@v; n = #) &)},
 {{v, {{-2, 2, 2}, Automatic, Automatic, Automatic}}, 
  Button["Reset", v = {{-2, 2, 2}, Automatic, Automatic, Automatic}] &}
 ]
```

It works on this example, but you have to be able to wrap the changing Graphics elements in `Dynamic`.

---

Alternative partial workaround:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[
  Sphere[{0, 0, #}] & /@ Range[n],
  ViewPoint -> Dynamic@$CellContext`v[[1]],
  ViewVertical -> Dynamic@$CellContext`v[[2]],
  ViewAngle -> Dynamic@$CellContext`v[[3]],
  ViewCenter -> Dynamic@$CellContext`v[[4]]
  ],
 {{n, 3}, 2, 12, 1,
  Appearance -> "Labeled",
  TrackingFunction -> ((v = N@v; n = #) &)},
 {{v, {{-2, 2, 2}, Automatic, Automatic, Automatic}}, 
  Button["Reset", $CellContext`v = v] &},
 Initialization :> ($CellContext`v = v)
 ]
```

The biggest criticism is that `` $CellContext`v `` is not localized.  If you create more than one output, or use the same name in two cells from two different codes, they will be the same variable. So, for instance, rotating the graphic in one `Manipulate` output will rotate the graphic in the others that use `` $CellContext`v `` in the same way.

It might also leave some `` Cell$$15247`v `` symbols lying about -- at least I had one, but they did not proliferate.